# Sharepoint Automation

Tags: automated-testing, xpath, testcase, sharepoint

I am trying to automate SharePoint test cases. I am finding an issue while finding an element locator for actual result, updated by, update date. Does anyone know how to find the locators?

HTML:

```
<i data-icon-name="Edit" class="ms-Button-icon icon-70" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

It's an edit icon where I have to click

Comment: Please share the html dom, what have you done so far and what is the issue that you are facing.

Comment: HTML:<i data-icon-name="Edit" class="ms-Button-icon icon-70" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i>    it's an edit icon where i have to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straight-forward. Try the below xpath for locating the element.

```
"//i[@data-icon-name='Edit']"
```

You might also add the role attribute in the xpath but I think this would be sufficient. I am not sure if this is clickable, if not then write the locator for its parent element in the DOM.

It's better to share the some portion of the DOM not a single tag.